# Проблема с установкой Magento 2

Tags: magento

При установке Magento 2 выбивает:
Fatal error: Class Magento\Framework\DataObject contains 2 abstract methods and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (ArrayAccess::, ArrayAccess::AsyncInsert) in F:\App\OpenServer\domains\madento\vendor\magento\framework\DataObject.php on line 14

Answer (score 0):

Версия Magento 2.x.x и php ?

Можно попробовать объявить эти методы как abstract в интерфейсе или же реализовать в данном классе их функционал(но это не решит самой сути проблемы а только эот баг).

Такой ошибки ни разу не попадалось при установке от 2.0 до 2.1.3.